# TouchXML over release problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, touchxml

I'm getting an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error when I release a CXMLDocument.

Here's my very simple code which has no dependencies:

```
@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSError *xmlError = nil;    
    CXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<test></test>" options:0 error:&xmlError];
    CXMLElement *rootElement = [xmlDoc rootElement]; // Unused local variable   
    [xmlDoc release];
}
```

If I comment out `CXMLElement *rootElement = [xmlDoc rootElement];` or if I retain it, there is no error.

How can calling `[xmlDoc rootElement]` cause xmlDoc to get over released? Is this a TouchXML bug or am I missing something really basic?

Similar question here, but no valid answers: [Weird crash if I try to release CXMLDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723470/weird-crash-if-i-try-to-release-cxmldocument)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash goes away when I turn Guard Malloc turned off. Assuming that Guard Malloc is reliable, this looks like it's a Touch XML bug.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the correct way of getting rootElement? I've never used TouchXML but from what I can find, it seems that getting the rootElement is done accordingly

```
NSArray *foundRoots = [theXMLDocument nodesForXPath:@"//Root"  error:&xmlError]; 
CXMLElement Root = [foundRoots objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I think that's equivalent to my code. I get the same EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: Are you sure there are any roots in your xml? Not any typos in there?

Comment: Yup it finds one root @"//test" in this XML: @"<test>Test!</test>"

Answer (score 0):

I used TouchXML quite often, and (fortunately?) I did not have this problem up to now, but it just happened ...

I posted a solution here:
[Memory crash using [CXMLNode nodesForXPath] with namespace mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875252/memory-crash-using-cxmlnode-nodesforxpath-with-namespace-mappings/18976025#18976025)